# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-session broken post installation script

Tags: apt, gnome, dpkg, 18.04, gnome-session

On a a minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04, I attempted to switch to a vanilla gnome desktop by running:
`sudo apt-get install vanilla-gnome-desktop`

This installation failed due to [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1761014) This issue is causing all apt-get install and apt-get upgrade's to fail.

I have attempted to remove the broken package(s) with the following commands, to no avail:

```
hugh@xps:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gnome-session (3.28.1-0ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package gnome-session (--configure):
 installed gnome-session package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-session
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and:

```
hugh@xps:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq gnome-session
(Reading database ... 166375 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gnome-session (3.28.1-0ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package gnome-session (--remove):
 installed gnome-session package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-session
```

and

```
hugh@xps:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for gnome-session:amd64
```

Comment: Please add output of the `ls -al /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` command to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually */etc/alternatives/gdm3.css* points to */usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css*. The latter file is located in [`gnome-shell-common` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/gnome-shell-common/filelist).
You can reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-common --reinstall
```

If it does not work you can try to fix the problem by recreating the link manually with

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
```

And then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked - I had to delete gdm3.css and recreate the symlink.